# HighCharts - display ratio charts

Tags: highcharts

I want to create a chart similar to http://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-negative
but instead of 0 I want to use 1 as a mirror to show lower values (like negative values)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Threshold** does the trick. Like in this example: http://jsfiddle.net/n96Kc/

```
series: {
            allowPointSelect: true,
            threshold: 100,
        }
```

In your case the threshold needs to be set to 1 of course.